# How does blog comments works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs

I was watching rails tutorial by mckenzie https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BI_VnnOLSKY and cannot understand how he makes the comments work for each post. _form partial looks like this:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>

<% end %>
```

So why does he has to call for this [@post, @post.comments.build] ??

Then he makes another partial for _comments that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <h3><%= comment.name %></h3>
    <p><%= comment.description %></p>
</div>
```

So, how is he able to just call for "comment.name" without using the @ sign if there is no loop going on like @comment.each do |comment|

Then he renders everything in the post/show.html.erb like this:

```
<h2><%= @post.comments.count %> Comments</h2>
<%= render @post.comments %>
```

In the second line how is the able to call for comments as a method just taking this for the _comment partial??

Finally heres how the comments controller:

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)

    redirect_to post_path(@post)

end
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hopefully this will help.

````<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
````
Tells it to post to the post_comments_path(post_id). This requires you to have that route and controller setup. 

````render @post.comments
````Tells it to render a collection as @post.comments returns an array of ActiveRecord objects. Essentially it iterates of the array and renders the partial for each instance of comment.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass an array to `render` as he does with `render @post.comments` then some magick happens and rails renders each comment using the `_comment` partial. It's all described in the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html).